# WSO2 ESB Xpath and getting child nodes

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using a payload Factory and I want to select all the child nodes of the parent node. The problem is when I select all the child nodes using different Xpath expressions it returns the values but none of the nodes.

so rather than getting what I want

```
    <child1>value1</child1>
    <child2>value2</child2>
    <child3>value3</child3>
```

I'm getting this

```
value1value2value3
```

The different Xpath expressions I've tried so far are

```
parent/child::node()
parent/node()
parent//*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer leaf nodes, you will get their values.
If you refer nodes having child nodes, you will get xml fragments.

Input message :

```
<parent>
  <child>value1</child>
  <child>value2</child>
  <child>value3</child>
</parent>
```

Payload factory :

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
<format>
      <result xmlns="">
        $1
      </result>
</format>
<args>
   <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//parent"/>
</args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Result :

```
<result>
  <parent>
    <child>value1</child>
    <child>value2</child>
    <child>value3</child>
  </parent>
</result>
```

Payload factory :

```
...
<arg evaluator="xml" expression="//child"/>
...
```

Result :

```
<result>value1value2value3</result>
```

Don't know how to solve that with payloadFactory, but you can use XSLT or javascript

Sample using javascript :

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
  mc.setPayloadXML(<result>{mc.getPayloadXML()..*::child}</result>);
]]></script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the script mediator as it looks easy enough. My problem is that ..*::child returns nothing and I think it's to do with the namespaces that gets added to the XML, when I try to add a namespace it removes it as it causes an error in the script mediator

Comment: if elements <child> belongs to namespace _http://myns, modify javascript like this : var ns = new Namespace('_http://myns');
mc.setPayloadXML(<result>{mc.getPayloadXML()..ns::child}</result>);

Comment: For more details on how to manage xml in javascript, have a look there : _https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/JavaScript_Guide/Traitement_de_XML_avec_E4X (I let you find the english version...)

Comment: Using the following doesn't work it seems to throw errors when I try to add in the var for the namespace and removes it

Comment: Sorry, can't help you, it works well for me even if I copy/paste content of my upside note in my test Proxy, using ESB Console or editing the xml source file from the filesystem... I'm working with WSO2 ESB v4.8.1   My proxy content :    <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <script language="js">var ns = new Namespace('_http://myns'); mc.setPayloadXML(&lt;result&gt;{mc.getPayloadXML()..ns::child}&lt;/result&gt;);</script>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>

Comment: You can use CDATA as I use it in my reply if you don't want to see &lt; &gt;

Comment: I was unable to solve it using the JavaScript as it was removing any variables I tried to set. I have now solved my problem and have no need for the payload or script mediator but thanks for your help!